# Upload form does not work in Firefox 3 with Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, firefox, upload

Today, I ran into this weird problem with a user using Mac OS X. This user always had a failed upload. The form uses a regular "input type=file". The user could upload using any browser except Firefox 3 on his Mac. Only this particular user was seeing this error.

Obviously, the problem is only with this one particular user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User corrected this weird problem by recreating their FireFox profile.
[How to manage FireFox profiles](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing+profiles)

I imagine a re-install of FireFox would have corrected the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I imagine a re-install of FireFox would have corrected the problem as well.

Profile related problems cannot usually be solved by re-installing Firefox since reinstalling (or upgrading) would re-use the same "damaged" profile.

Comment: unless you remove the user account files as well.